# Quelle est la différence entre prédire et pronostic ?

Tags: vocabulaire

On peut dire

> prédire le match de foot

et on peut dire

> pronostic le match de foot

et ils peuvent venir ensemble aussi

> prédire le pronostic des patients

Comment: *Pronostic le match de foo* n'est pas correct. Ce peut être par exemple *pronostiquer le résultat du match de foot* ou *ton pronostic pour le match xxx.*

Comment: De même qu'on ne dit pas "prédire le match de foot" mais "prédire le résultat du match de foot". Sauf que dans ce cas, l'usage veut qu'on dise "pronostiquer le résultat du match de foot". On sous entend que le pronostic est basé sur des faits et la connaissances des joueurs et des équipes ... Alors que "prédire" est plus imprécis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Prédire* signifie que l'on devine ce qui va se passer dans le futur. Typiquement, c'est ce que fera un(e) voyant(e), ou ce que peuvent faire des journalistes, des spécialistes d'un domaine,etc., sur base de leur analyse.

Ex:

> Madame Soleil prédit que François Hollande sera le prochain président
>
> Les analystes boursiers prédisent une chute du dollar

*Prédire* un match de football est assez inattendu. Cela impliquerait que la personne arrive à deviner quels seront les faits de jeu et le déroulement d'un match. On n'entendra pas souvent un journaliste sportif dire qu'il va "prédire" un match de football, mais plutôt qu'il va le *pronostiquer*, cest-à-dire qu'il tentera de deviner le score ou résultat final. Ou alors, il peut par exemple *prédire* que tel ou tel joueur sera sélectionné,  mais ce n'est pas vraiment un *pronostic*.

Donc, le *pronostic* d'un match ou une compétition est le score ou le résultat final qu'une personne tentera de deviner, par exemple dans les paris sportifs. Le *pronostic* au sens médical est la prévision faite sur l'évolution d'une maladie ou d'un accident, basé sur l'analyse médicale. C'est donc plus précis et plus spécifique qu'une *prédiction*.

Comment: Mais *prédire* n'est pas *prévoir*...